# how to use distinct in impala

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, impala, bigdata

HI I am trying to query the distinct localities in my table.

Here is my query.

```
select distinct city,locality, avg_sqft from real_estate.re_search where city = 'bangalore'  AND locality != 'jayanagar';
```

Result

```
+-----------+--------------+----------+
| city      | locality     | avg_sqft |
+-----------+--------------+----------+
| bangalore | bannerghatta | 13500    |
| bangalore | kormangala   | 18000    |
| bangalore | kodipur      | 7000     |
| bangalore | kormangala   | 16000    |
| bangalore | horamavu     | 9000     |
| bangalore | bellandur    | 15500    |
| bangalore | kodipur      | 9000     |
| bangalore | madivala     | 12000    |
| bangalore | varthur      | 12000    |
| bangalore | kormangala | 13500    |
| bangalore | bellandur    | 13000    |
| bangalore | kodipur      | 11500    |
| bangalore | kormangala   | 14000    |
```

the problem is I need to display the distinct locality in result.any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know the business use case but same locality has different square feet values in different rows. You can achieve distinct localities by doing below, if you can sum the values.       select city,locality, sum(avg_sqft ) from real_estate.re_search where city = 'bangalore'  AND locality != 'jayanagar' group by city,locality;

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get a list of distinct members of the locality column in your table, where the city is Bangalore by using the `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` operators:

```
SELECT city
      ,locality
      ,COUNT(locality)
FROM database.table
WHERE city = 'Bangalore'
GROUP BY city
        ,locality;
```